# System.UnauthorizedAccessException on Android Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am currently trying to make a Youtube Music downloader for Android in Xamarin. 
When I want to download the file, I get this error:

> Error:"System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path
>   "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Video Title.mp3" is denied.

I gave the app permission to write but I still get this Error. Why?

Comment: we can't debug code we can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting anything above android Marshmallow, not all permissions are going to be granted even if specified in the Manifest.

1) You need to specify the permissions you'll need (in this case read/write permissions maybe?) in the manifest.

2) You'll need to request permissions during runtime using [PermissionsPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin) (developed by good old James Montemagno!).

It's a really nice permissions library that's crazy simple to use. Go check it out and see if this fixes your issue.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me!!